# for const of minification

Tags: javascript, bundling-and-minification

I have the following typescript:

```
var mynames = new Array<string>();
mynames.push("Currency");
mynames.push("School_Id");
for (const mn of mynames) {
    console.log(mn);
}
```

Which is compiled into javascript:

```
var mynames = new Array();
mynames.push("Currency");
mynames.push("School_Id");
for (const mn of mynames) {
    console.log(mn);
}
```

Which is minified to:

```
n = [
];
n.push('Currency');
n.push('School_Id');
for (const n of n) console.log(n);
```

Which causes the exception:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'n' before initialization
```

Why am I getting an error when the code has been minified and not before?

Comment: Are we sure the last minification is correct?

Comment: "*Why am I getting an error when the code has been minified and not before?*" because the minified code contains an error, the real code does not.

Answer (score -1):

You are defining a variable with the same name with the array variable.
use another name like:

```
for (const m of n) console.log(n);
```

Comment: it's the minification that's causing this issue, that line cannot be changed as it is auto generated